# How to configure Android App Bundles to publish apk (PWA) on Google Play?

Tags: java, android, google-play, progressive-web-apps

I have created an application using **TWA** (com.github.GoogleChrome: custom-tabs-client).

But when publishing Google shows me an optimization error message and suggests to optimize using the Android App Bundles.
After reading a lot of information in Google, I was able to add the **Dynamic Feature Module** and enable minification. As a result, the apk was reduced to **700kb** from **2mb**, but Google still does not accept it.

Tell me please how to configure the assembly so that Google could approve the application?

Answer (score 0):

When building the application, you should select the assembly through the Android App Bundles

After assembly, you need to upload aab file instead of apk in google play

[solution](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1059760/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-android-app-bundles-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-apk-pwa)